# Screen shot failed on newest android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I installed newest android studio in my new PC and develop with it. While I take a screen shot. It always shows dialog written "

> unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device:EOF

[image]

Another way:
I tried to pull some files from my phone to PC. The process was always locked. The percent shew 448KB/1.2MB till I disconnected my phone and it was failed to translate files.
[image]

I think it is an issue of newest android studio. And how to fix it.

Comment: have you disabled screenshots for this activity in .java file?

Comment: I think it is not. I can take screen shot with adb command at the same time.

Comment: Did you tried with restart android studio?

Comment: Yes. But the problem still appeared.